# keras model.predict(x_test) throws ValueError: Input 0 of layer "U-Net" is incompatible with the layer

Tags: keras, input, valueerror, predict

i trained a U-Net for a segmentation problem. When I want to test its predictions i get a value error, that states the input shape is not fitting although the input has the correct shape:

`y_predicted = model.predict(x_test)` gives me:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "U-Net" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(32, 256, 3)
```

The plotted input image has correct shape and `x_test.shape`  gives me:

```
(256, 256, 3)
```

I cannot see where the shape can possibly change. Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing the samples dimension, should be (1, 256, 256, 3)

Comment: well... always nice to find out that the solution to your problem is a very simple one. 
That did it, thank you!